# MAC OSX-Android emulator launches but the app never runs.Tried reinstalling with no help

Tags: eclipse, macos, android-emulator

I am using eclipse helios and creating the sample project using android 2.3. The emulator starts fine but the program never launches and finally after 10 mins get this error:

```
[2010-12-13 21:51:21 - ApiDemos] ------------------------------
[2010-12-13 21:51:21 - ApiDemos] Android Launch!
[2010-12-13 21:51:21 - ApiDemos] adb is running normally.
[2010-12-13 21:51:21 - ApiDemos] Performing com.example.android.apis.ApiDemos activity launch
[2010-12-13 21:51:21 - ApiDemos] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'abhi'
[2010-12-13 21:51:21 - ApiDemos] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'abhi'
[2010-12-13 21:51:31 - Emulator] 2010-12-13 21:51:31.690 emulator[5496:903] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
[2010-12-13 21:51:31 - ApiDemos] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2010-12-13 21:51:31 - ApiDemos] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2010-12-13 21:53:19 - ApiDemos] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2010-12-13 21:53:19 - ApiDemos] Device API version is 9 (Android 2.3)
[2010-12-13 21:53:19 - ApiDemos] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-12-13 21:53:19 - ApiDemos] Uploading ApiDemos.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-12-13 21:53:22 - ApiDemos] Installing ApiDemos.apk...
[2010-12-13 21:55:30 - ApiDemos] Failed to install ApiDemos.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2010-12-13 21:55:30 - ApiDemos] (null)
[2010-12-13 21:55:30 - ApiDemos] Launch canceled!
```

Here is logcat error output:

```
12-13 21:53:14.836: ERROR/System(76): Failure starting core service
12-13 21:53:14.836: ERROR/System(76): java.lang.SecurityException
12-13 21:53:14.836: ERROR/System(76):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
12-13 21:53:14.836: ERROR/System(76):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
12-13 21:53:14.836: ERROR/System(76):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
12-13 21:53:14.836: ERROR/System(76):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:206)
12-13 21:53:14.886: ERROR/EventHub(76): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
12-13 21:53:14.886: ERROR/EventHub(76): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
12-13 21:53:15.705: ERROR/SoundPool(76): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-13 21:53:15.705: ERROR/SoundPool(76): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
12-13 21:53:15.715: ERROR/SoundPool(76): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
12-13 21:53:15.715: ERROR/SoundPool(76): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
12-13 21:53:15.715: ERROR/SoundPool(76): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
12-13 21:53:15.746: ERROR/UsbObserver(76): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 21:53:15.746: ERROR/UsbObserver(76):     at com.android.server.UsbObserver.init(UsbObserver.java:131)
12-13 21:53:15.746: ERROR/UsbObserver(76):     at com.android.server.UsbObserver.<init>(UsbObserver.java:65)
12-13 21:53:15.746: ERROR/UsbObserver(76):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:402)
12-13 21:53:28.686: ERROR/ThrottleService(76): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
12-13 21:53:29.455: ERROR/ThrottleService(76): Error reading data file
12-13 21:53:31.165: ERROR/logwrapper(180): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
12-13 21:53:31.285: ERROR/logwrapper(181): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
12-13 21:53:31.426: ERROR/logwrapper(182): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
12-13 21:53:32.105: ERROR/logwrapper(183): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
12-13 21:53:32.175: ERROR/logwrapper(184): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
12-13 21:53:32.386: ERROR/logwrapper(185): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76): ANR in com.android.settings
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76): Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED cmp=com.android.settings/.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider }
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76): Load: 4.21 / 1.33 / 0.47
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76): CPU usage from 2209ms to -7278ms ago:
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   29% 76/system_server: 17% user + 12% kernel / faults: 659 minor 2 major
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   17% 246/android.process.acore: 13% user + 4.2% kernel / faults: 1085 minor 1 major
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   13% 166/com.android.phone: 6.4% user + 7.1% kernel / faults: 536 minor 5 major
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   10% 232/zygote: 2.8% user + 7.8% kernel / faults: 725 minor 3 major
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   7.1% 234/zygote: 4.9% user + 2.1% kernel / faults: 1187 minor
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   5% 88/bootanimation: 4.1% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 1 minor
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   3.2% 169/com.android.systemui: 2.1% user + 1% kernel / faults: 205 minor
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   0.6% 32/rild: 0.2% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 7 minor
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   0.1% 1//init: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 1 minor
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   0.1% 38/qemud: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   0.1% 162/jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 49 minor
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   0% 41/adbd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 11 minor
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   0.2% 176/com.android.defcontainer: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 58 minor
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   0.1% 13/kswapd0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   0% 28/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   0% 33/zygote: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 21 minor
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   0.1% 35/installd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 3 minor
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):  +0% 275/<pre-initialized>: 0% user + 0% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):  +0% 285/dexopt: 0% user + 0% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76): 100% TOTAL: 54% user + 45% kernel + 0.1% irq + 0.1% softirq
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76): CPU usage from 5641ms to 6687ms later:
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   27% 76/system_server: 12% user + 14% kernel / faults: 82 minor 1 major
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):     10% 90/ActivityManager: 4.2% user + 6.3% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):     7.3% 85/SurfaceFlinger: 3.1% user + 4.2% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):     3.1% 214/Binder Thread #: 2.1% user + 1% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):     1% 81/Compiler: 1% user + 0% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):     1% 82/Binder Thread #: 0% user + 1% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):     1% 83/Binder Thread #: 0% user + 1% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):     1% 84/Binder Thread #: 1% user + 0% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):     1% 96/PackageManager: 1% user + 0% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):     1% 119/WindowManagerPo: 1% user + 0% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):     1% 219/Binder Thread #: 1% user + 0% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):     1% 268/Binder Thread #: 1% user + 0% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   26% 246/android.process.acore: 21% user + 4.5% kernel / faults: 101 minor
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):     8% 246/d.process.acore: 4.5% user + 3.4% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):     2.2% 251/Compiler: 1.1% user + 1.1% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):    +0% 286/LegacyContactIm: 0% user + 0% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   13% 166/com.android.phone: 0% user + 13% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):     13% 168/HeapWorker: 0% user + 13% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   6.9% 232/com.android.launcher: 2.3% user + 4.6% kernel / faults: 209 minor
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):     8.1% 232/ndroid.launcher: 2.3% user + 5.8% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):    +0% 287/AsyncTask #1: 0% user + 0% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   5.3% 88/bootanimation: 5.3% user + 0% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):     5.3% 94/BootAnimation: 5.3% user + 0% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   0.2% 35/installd: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 3 minor
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):   0.3% 234/com.android.settings: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 3 minor
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):     0.3% 235/HeapWorker: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76):  +0% 285/dexopt: 0% user + 0% kernel
12-13 21:54:21.178: ERROR/ActivityManager(76): 100% TOTAL: 46% user + 53% kernel
12-13 21:55:01.738: ERROR/ThrottleService(76): Error reading data file
12-13 21:55:26.347: ERROR/MetadataRetrieverClient(34): failed to extract an album art
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling the sdk, i was still getting the screen showing app loaded but the actual app was not showing up. After pressing the Menu screen the app shows up. I think this needs to be in the FAQ as it is a trivial but perplexing problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you have in your AndroidManifest.xml, as a `<manifest>` attribute:

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```